# How to add calculated field to Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, calculated-field

I am building a database system and am trying to add calculated field to model as well as the template. I want to field to automatically generate the result of to the values entered on two fields.

**This is my model.py:**

```
class VinanPet(models.Model):
    transaction_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    entry_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    tank_Opening = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    tank_Closing = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    tank_Difference = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    pump_Opening = models.FloatField(null=True)
    pump_Closing = models.FloatField(null=True)
    pump_Difference = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    expenses = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    bank = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    teller_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    teller = models.ImageField(upload_to="teller", null=True)
```

**And this is my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
import calculation
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
from .models import VinanPet

class ManagerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = VinanPet
        fields = "__all__"
        widget = {
            'entry_Date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'tank_Difference': forms.DecimalField(disabled=True,widget=calculation.FormulaInput('tank_Opening-tank_Closing'))
        }
```

The calculated field only work on form not on database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is added in Django yet as a feature. You can overwrite the `save()` method or use Django `pre_save()` signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Django ComputedFields library: https://django-computedfields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#basic-usage

```
from django.db import models
from computedfields.models import ComputedFieldsModel, computed, compute

class Person(ComputedFieldsModel):
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @computed(models.CharField(max_length=32), depends=[('self', ['surname', 'forename'])])
    def combined(self):
        return f'{self.surname}, {self.forename}'
```

Second thing to consider is to just use `property`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-property-decorator-property/

In this case it will not be stored in DB, but calculated on the fly when needed